# query to check srid of features in feature class?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, srid, st-geometry

What query should I use to check the SRID of the features in a feature class? The storage type of the feature class in st_geometry?

I tried the following query but no luck :

select top 1 [geomColumnName].STSrid
from [schema].[feature class];

Comment: It's not obvious, but this is an Oracle question, while the "duplicate" is SQL Server. This is **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this question I did some more research and testing. I found the query:

SELECT sde.st_srid (SHAPE) sridcol FROM schema.featureclassname;

I referred to the following link:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-srid.htm

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the Oracle version and geometry storage since SDO_GEOMETRY would be a very different query. Esri doesn't permit more than one SRID per geometry column, so you can LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following syntax

```
SELECT [geomColumnName].STSrid as srid, * FROM [schema].[tableName]
```

I got this from the following [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/how-i-get-srid-from-geometry-field)

personally I would just use the following since the srid will be the same for all features in a feature class:

```
SELECT distinct [geomColumnName].STSrid as srid FROM [schema].[tableName]
```